# How to integrate an expression holding Series[]?

Tags: numerical-integration, series-expansion

How do you integrate with the `Series` command in the Integral?

I.e., it looks something like:

```
NIntegrate[(E^x α)/(Series[E^(x α), {x, 0, 3}] - Series[E^x, {x, 0, 3}] Subscript[λ, R] + 
Subscript[λ, R]) /. {θ -> 1, α -> 1/3, Subscript[λ, R] -> 0.5}, {x, 1, ∞}]
```

Comment: `Series` returns a special `SeriesData` object that is different from what it looks like.  Use `Normal` to convert it to a plain expression.  See 2nd item under Possible Issues in `Series` documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @Szabolcs, the issue is with the structure of `Series`

```
Series[E^(x α), {x, 0, 3}]
```

> [image]

We need to remove `O[x]^4` to be able to integrate the expression containing `Series`. Thus to get "Normal expression", we should use `Normal`,

```
a = Normal[Series[E^(x α), {x, 0, 3}]]
b = Normal[Series[E^x, {x, 0, 3}]]
NIntegrate[((E^(x*α))/(a - b Subscript[λ, R] +  Subscript[λ, R])) /. {θ -> 1, α -> 1/3, 
   Subscript[λ, R] -> 0.5}, {x, 1, ∞}]
```

But, still we are getting error messages, this is because $\exp{(\infty)}$ is $\infty$.

Comment: I made the expansion finite so it works...Thanks!

Comment: @PMF You are welcome!